# c1 truedbgrid make third column auto compute by the values of two column

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, truedbgrid

Code for dataset:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DENOMINATION");
dt.Columns.Add("COUNT");
dt.Columns.Add("TOTAL");

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1000", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "500", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "200", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "100", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "50", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "20", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "10", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "5", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0.25", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0.10", "0", "0" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0.05", "0", "0" });

ds.Tables.Add(dt);

dgDENOM.AllowUpdate = true;
dgDENOM.SetDataBinding(dt, "", true);
```

In UI:

```
DENOMINATION    COUNT     TOTAL
1000            0         0
500             0         0
```

What I want in real time/runtime, the column count will be modified and after that the value of total = denomination * count. I will put it on a event of the db grid.

**Sample output**

```
DENOMINATION    COUNT     TOTAL
1000            5         5000
500             4         2000
```

Answer (score 0):

In c1TrueDbGrid you can have an unbound column.
You populate that column using the [C1TrueDBGrid.UnboundColumnFetch](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/docs/c1truedbgrid/c1truedbgridunboundcolumnfetchevent.htm) event.

The [UnboundColumnFetchEventArgs](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/docs/c1truedbgrid/unboundcolumnfetcheventargsmembers.htm) class contains readonly properties for the grid row, column, and column index, and a read/write property for value.

Use the `Value` property to set the cell value for each row - something like this (untested):

```
private void c1TrueDBGrid1_UnboundColumnFetch(object sender, UnboundColumnFetchEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.Row;
    var denomination = (int)grid.Columns["DENOMINATION"].CellValue(row);
    var count = (int)grid.Columns["COUNT"].CellValue(row);
    e.value = denomination * count;
}
```